# Windows Event Log does not work

Tags: windows, events, services, logging

On my Windows 7 Ultimate system the Event Log service does not start anymore.  I get the response `Error 2: Cannot find the file specified`. I checked my system, but unfortunately I couldn't find any reason for this behavior. All log directories exists (`System32\winevt`). It could be a permission problem at one of these directories.

Also `sfc /scannow` can't find any reason (successfully).

The bad thing is, that all dependent services also stopped working:

- Task Manager
- Cd/Dvd Rom drives
- other drivers

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Error 2
>
> If you have the above error (Cannot find the file specified) when trying to start the windows event log, then have no fear, for I may have the solution. If you have tried everything else online, then try this fix.
> Open up regedit, and delete the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters
```

> Basically, a hotfix (not sure which) malforms that registry key, rendering the event log useless.

[Source of Information](http://www.unauthorised-access.com/2011/05/error-2-when-starting-windows-event-log/)

Comment: It can also be sign of malware